# Why increasing stove flame will boil milk faster?

Tags: thermodynamics

In Gas Cutting, skilled person use **less** flame to cut the work piece faster,

But in case of stove flame, **increasing** the flame will make milk boil faster.

In both cases heat is same, but heat generated by flame is acting different. why so?

Comment: To boil faster (more liquid turned to vapor) you need to add more enthalpy to accomplish the phase transition. A skilled welder uses a more precise flame and a steadier hand to deliver less heat into a smaller area/volume to cut faster. Two totally different things.

Comment: @JonCuster Is it not worth asking here?. can i remove it now before piling with **down votes** with sombody answered & not allow me to delete it. [**like this**](http://i.imgur.com/XjEgeYJ.jpg)